# Is (forward-char N)'s runtime complexity O(N)?

Tags: motion, performance

Internally, the text of a buffer is stored as a char array. The encoding used is based on `UTF-8`, which may use a variable number of bytes to represent different code points. Does the variable-length nature of the encoding mean that `(forward-char N)`'s runtime complexity is `O(N)`? Or maybe other operations are `O(N)`?